# Php $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PATCH'

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I have create my own rest api making only php code and json file in my local server or my website file manager to use it as rest api and i mostly did it. server request methods post, get, put and delete are working while patch is not working.
Any one help me please.
Here is my php code

index.php

```
<?php
    
if(!array_key_exists('path', $_GET)){
    echo 'this path not exist';
    exit;
}
$path = explode('/', $_GET['path']);
$path1 = explode('/', $_GET['item']);
if(count($path) == 0 || $path[0] == ""){
    echo 'this path not exist';
    exit;
}
$param1 = "";
if(count($path)>1){
    $param1 = $path[1];
}
$contents = file_get_contents('db.json');
$json =  json_decode($contents, true);
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
header('Content-type: application/json');
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
     
function findById($vector, $param1){
    $id = -1;
    foreach($vector as $key => $obj){
        if($obj['id'] == $param1){
            $id = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $id;
}
     
if($method === 'GET'){
    if($json[$path[0]]){
        if($param1 == ""){
            echo json_encode($json[$path[0]]);
        }else{
            $id = findById($json[$path[0]], $param1);
            if($id>=0){
                echo json_encode($json[$path[0]][$id]);
            }else{
                echo 'Error';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo '[]';
    }
}
if($method === 'POST'){
    $jsonBody = json_decode($body, true);
    $jsonBody['id'] = time();
    $json[$path[0]][] = $jsonBody;
    echo json_encode($jsonBody);
    file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($json));
}
     
if($method === 'DELETE'){
    if($json[$path[0]]){
        if($param1 == ""){
            echo 'error';
        }else{
            $id = findById($json[$path[0]], $param1);
            if($id>=0){
                echo json_encode($json[$path[0]][$id]);
                unset($json[$path[0]][$id]);
                file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($json));
            }else{
                echo 'Error';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
     
if($method === 'PUT'){
    if($json[$path[0]]){
        if($param1 == ""){
            echo 'error';
        }else{
            $id = findById($json[$path[0]], $param1);
            if($id>=0){
                $jsonBody = json_decode($body, true);
                $jsonBody['id'] = $param1;
                $json[$path[0]][$id] = $jsonBody;
                echo json_encode($json[$path[0]][$id]);
                file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($json));
            }else{
                echo 'Error';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
     
if($method === 'PATCH'){
    if($json[$path[0]]){
        if($param1 == ""){
            echo 'error';
        }else{
            $id = findById($json[$path[0]], $param1);
            if($id>=0){
                $jsonBody = json_decode($body, true);
                $jsonBody['id'] = $param1;
                $json[$path[0]][$id][$path1] = $jsonBody;
                echo json_encode($json[$path[0]][$id][$path1]);
                file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($json));
            }else{
                echo 'Error';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
?>
```

And here i have json file
db.json

```
{
  "users":[
       {
         "id":652888473,
         "name":"ali"
       },
       {
         "id":699266789,
         "name":"joseph"
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: "patch is not working" -- what is it doing instead of what you expect? Are you sure the webserver is configured to run scripts when the PATCH method is used?

Comment: other methods are working while patch is not working

Comment: Maybe there is a message in the webserver's log which tells you what went wrong (i.e. method is not allowed, ...)?

Comment: No the server is only showing the error which i have been defined in my code. Some thing went wrong in patch method in my code. any one do it better.

Comment: You have several `echo "error";` in the PATCH section. You should echo different messages so you know which condition is failing. Also dump all the relevant variables. There's no way to know what the problem is without detailed debugging information.

Comment: As Barmar's first comment says, "not working" is not a useful problem description - what is the expected behaviour, and what behaviour are you seeing instead?

Comment: For example i wanna update any item in json list array. So it replaces that item for whole array list except id. I wanna update part of  items and others remain the same as they are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
if($method === 'PATCH'){
    if($json[$path[0]]){
        if($param1 == ""){
            echo 'error';
        }else{
            $id = findById($json[$path[0]], $param1);
            if($id>=0){
                $jsonBody = json_decode($body, true);
                $json[$path[0]][$id] = array_marge($json[$path[0]][$id], $jsonBody);
                echo json_encode($json[$path[0]][$id][$path1]);
                file_put_contents('db.json', json_encode($json));
            }else{
                echo 'Error';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).